# Can a Linux kernel module use UIO if it does not use any physical hardware?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am planning on building a Linux kernel module which will need to interface with a user-space device driver, and I will need to export data to user-space. After some reading I figured that the UIO interface might be what I need.

I looked at some examples and they are all based on the assumption that the kernel module itself will interact directly with hardware, and reference things like a device structure, interrupts, etc.

Is it possible to write a software only kernel module and still use the UIO library? Or would just using sysfs directly be a better approach?

EDIT: I am attaching some test code I was working on. The goal was to try and read a string from user-space through the UIO interface, but I don't think this will work since I cannot see how to properly initiate a `struct device` which I think is required for `uio_register_device`.

```
#include <linux/module.h>  // Needed by all modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>  // Needed for KERN_ALERT

#include <linux/uio_driver.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>    // GFP_ defs
#include <linux/device.h>

char test_data[] = "This is some test data to read in user-space via UIO\n";

int init_module(void)
{
  struct uio_info *info;
  struct device *dev;
  info = kzalloc(sizeof(struct uio_info), GFP_KERNEL);
  if (!info)
    return -ENOMEM;

  // need to use struct device for uio_register_device
  dev = kzalloc(sizeof(struct device), GFP_KERNEL);
  dev->parent = 0;
  dev->init_name = "UIO test driver";

  info->name = "uio_test";
  info->version = "0.0.1";

  info->mem[0].size = sizeof(test_data);
  info->mem[0].memtype = UIO_MEM_LOGICAL;
  info->mem[0].addr = (phys_addr_t) kmalloc(sizeof(test_data), GFP_KERNEL);
  snprintf((char *) info->mem[0].addr, sizeof(test_data), "%s", test_data);

  info->irq = UIO_IRQ_NONE;

  // now we need to register the device for it to create /dev/uioN and sysfs files
  if (uio_register_device(dev, info)) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "uio_test: couldn't register UIO device\n");
    kfree(dev);
    kfree((char *) info->mem[0].addr);
    kfree(info);
    return -ENODEV;
  }

  printk(KERN_ALERT "uio_test: init complete\n");

  return 0;
}


void cleanup_module(void)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "uio_test: exit\n");
}  

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: If you share with us your final goal -- we would probably be of better help. Seems like [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Sorry for the lack of details, but along the lines of your other comment my final goal is actually a networking component that would sit alongside TCP/IP, and utilize a user space driver for a software defined radio. So I want a kernel space access for the network, but user-space facilities for the signal processing. I was looking into UIO as a way of sharing a data path from the networking to the physical side above.

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to make your networking work in kernel-space? And why? Maybe we can suggest you user-space way to do that work, if you can share with us more details.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point behind the kernel driver is to talk to hardware.  If you don't have any hardware, then you probably don't need a kernel driver at all.

What is kernel module doing, if it isn't talking to hardware?  Where is getting its data from?  To answer your question, it is totally possible to write a kernel driver that doesn't actually talk to hardware and still talks to UIO, but I'm not sure what it would actually say.

Comment: Well, there **are** kernel modules that are not talking to any hardware (at least directly), but those are still valuable modules. Examples: iptables/netfilter modules, filesystem modules (ext4, FUSE, etc). Also, your CPU and RAM are also hardware, and sometimes you need to have kernel module just to handle those resources more directly or efficiently, for some custom applications.

Comment: Yes, we are actually working on a network stack of sorts. We want to be able to utilize certain features of the kernel for that task, but then use a user space driver. I am still reading the interfaces for UIO, and wondering how I would handle things like the device struct if I don't actually have a hardware device.

Comment: @Mr.Shickadance What exactly you are planning to expose to user-space from your module? How much data, in which form, etc.? There a lot of kernel-to-userspace interfaces you can use, UIO is only one of them, and vey specific one. Are you sure you really need that one?

Comment: @SamProtsenko I can't really talk about the kernel module itself, but you are correct. I don't necessarily need UIO, but some kind of interface to user-space that will be sufficient for passing network traffic through. I am definitely open to suggestions. Sorry that I can't be more specific about the whole project, for now I am just looking into this interface with a user-space driver.

Comment: @Mr.Shickadance Take a look at [Netlink sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink). As you have network packets it seems logical to use socket-based interface with user-space. Or you can create [character device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices). I don't know internal details, but if it's networking traffic -- why don't let kernel networking stack do its job and handle it for you, so you can catch packets in user-space just by opening socket.?

Comment: If you just want some sort of user space interface, then you should use either sysfs or ioctls, depending on which is more robust.

Comment: @TimurTabi + netlink, which is also a type of kernel <-> userspace interface.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, @SamProtsenko. I've seen that before but it completely slipped my mind. Thanks!